# Access "public" struct defined inside a class

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a class whose private member has to access a struct defined with public access in the same class. I am using VS Code to write the code. When I try to write a private member function, it says the struct identifier is not defined.

```
class Planner
{
  private:
    typedef std::pair<int, int> location;
    std::vector<location> obstacles;
    Pose next_state(const Pose& current_state, const Command& command);

  public:
    Planner(/* args */);
    virtual ~Planner();

    /* data */
    struct Command
    {
        unsigned char direction;
        unsigned char steering;
    };

    struct Pose
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        int theta;
    };

    struct Node
    {
        Pose pose;
        int f;
        int g;
        int h;
    };
};
```

Here, it says 'identifier "Pose" is undefined'. I would like to understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider also: you may slightly re-arrange your code without adding lines.

```
class Planner
{
private:
   typedef std::pair<int, int> location;
   std::vector<location> obstacles;
   // "next_state" private method moved below

public:
   Planner(/* args */){};
   virtual ~Planner(){};

   /* data */
   struct Command
   {
      unsigned char direction;
      unsigned char steering;
   };

   struct Pose
   {
      int x;
      int y;
      int theta;
   };

   struct Node
   {
      Pose pose;
      int f;
      int g;
      int h;
   };

private:
   Pose next_state(const Pose& current_state, const Command& command);

};
```

You may have more than one private section.

Also, you might consider moving all the private attributes together at the end of class declaration.

Comment: Of course, the other way round re-arranging instead of _forward declarations_ works as well. Good alternative.

Answer (score 4):

> Here, it says 'identifier "Pose" is undefined'. I would like to understand what is going on here.

That's because you introduced `Pose` and `Command` type references before the compiler could see them in the `private` section:

```
private:
    // ...
    Pose next_state(const Pose& current_state, const Command& command);
                       // ^^^^                       ^^^^^^^
```

The compiler needs to see *identifiers* before their usage.

---

The way to solve that is you need properly ordered forward declarations within your `Planner` class:

```
class Planner {
  // <region> The following stuff in the public access section,
  // otherwise an error about "redeclared with different access" will occur.
  public:
    struct Pose;
    struct Command;
  // </region> 

  private:
    typedef std::pair<int, int> location;
    std::vector<location> obstacles;
    Pose next_state(const Pose& current_state, const Command& command);

  public:
    Planner(/* args */);
    virtual ~Planner();

    /* data */
    struct Command {
        unsigned char direction;
        unsigned char steering;
    };

    struct Pose {
        int x;
        int y;
        int theta;
    };

    struct Node {
        Pose pose;
        int f;
        int g;
        int h;
    };
};
```

See the [working code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7bec0e92a7b5c78).

The alternative is to rearrange your `public` and `private` sections<sup>1</sup> as mentioned in [@2785528's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55405169/1413395).

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Note these can be provided multipe times within a class declaration.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Files are parsed in order. You are referencing Pose before you are defining it. You can do this with member functions and variables but those are the exception not the rule.

An easy way to solve this in your case is to move the private section to the end.

Comment: Sidenote: Function definitions inside the class can side-step the ordering and use members declared later in the class.

Comment: @user4581301 I guess I did not understand your comment. What make this answer be erroneous?

Comment: Puzzled by that myself. Too simple? Forward declarations are more ideologically correct? No clue. I just wanted to point out that there was an exception to the Everything is processed in order, because most of the time what you said is correct.

Comment: The first version of this answer was bad (-1). Current version is mediocre, but we actually don't need it because we now have good answers.

Comment: @anatolyg: Neither of the other answers even attempt to explain what is wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I missed that aspect in the other answers!